# Why does python treat my script like an argument while running it?

Tags: python-2.7, arguments, interpreter

so I decided to go through each exercise (and each part of the exercise) in "learn python the hard way", and I came to this:

Combine `raw_input` with `argv` to make a script that gets more input from a user. Don't over think it. Just use `argv` to get something, and raw_input to get something else from the user.

So to comply with the exercise, I make this:

```
from sys import argv
name = argv
print "Your name is %s" %(name)
```

then when I run it (`python module.py myname`), this is the result:

```
Your name is ['module.py', 'myname']
```

Why does python treat module.py like it's an argument while simultaneously reading the script?

I know it would not do this if we were dealing with an exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` is an **array**, containing all arguments, including the 0th argument, which is the name by which the program was called; that's a C convention.

> I know it would not do this if we were dealing with an exe.

I claim that your claim is false. `argv[0]` should be the executable name, in that case.

Comment: but when I use programs like this in c, if i put the argument after the executable, the program treats itself like a binary program running and the argment like an argument.

Comment: no, in C, `argv` is an array, and `argv[0]` contains the executable name as called, too. Python is consistent with that.